# Swagger/Swashbuckle redirects to request url

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I use WebAPI 2 and setup Swashbuckle there.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration 
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "medEbridge2.API");
}).EnableSwaggerUi(c =>{
c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "UHG.mb2.WebApi.SwaggerExtensions.onComplete.js"); });
```

Then in javascript, I overwrite api_key with my bearer

```
window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add('oauth2', apiKeyAuth);
```

So, now when I press "Try it out!" swagger

1. Sends requests and received OK response (checked with Fiddler)
2. Redirects me to request url https://mb2-api-local.uhg.com.au/fhir/valueset/authoritytype/$expand

So now I have open empty page

Answer (score 0):

I did not do Oauth, but I have overridden swagger api_key with my token. But there I used custom HTML instead of customJS. Where you can configure your keys and token. 
You can get swaggerUI HTML from GitHub and modify it as required. 
Can you try it using

```
c.CustomAsset("index", thisAssembly, "yourHTMLHere.html");
```

and override keys there